# I am trying to implement a player score in my game of tic tac toe

Tags: javascript, html, tic-tac-toe

Okay, so i have a table in html that forms 9 squares, whenever a user clicks a square the background image changes to an x or o.. soon as a winner is seen an alert pops up, adds one to the players score variable and the game resets.

I am having trouble in getting the score variable to update and show a 1 instead of 0 when a player wins.

I'm not sure if its the syntax or placements of all my functions and what is inside them that is the problem.

any help is much appreciated.

```
<script>

    /*set both players scores to 0*/
        var playerxscore = 0;
        var playeroscore = 0;


    $(document).ready(function() {
        var playerturn = 0;
        /*initialise players turn, can alternate between values players*/


        /*label all squares by giving them ids (html)*/
        /* summon a click function in jQuery to run whenever a square is clicked*/
        $("#cell11, #cell12, #cell13, #cell21, #cell22, #cell23, #cell31, #cell32, #cell33").click(function() {

            /*call a new variable square and give its value to that of the table cell */
            var square = $(this);

            /*if its player 1's turn (0) place a O and swap players turn*/
            if (playerturn==0)  {                  
                playerturn = 1;
                square.css("background","url(player_x.png)");
                square.addClass("playerx");

            }  else {
                playerturn = 0;
                square.css("background","url(player_o.png)");
                square.addClass("playero");
            }



            /* if o win statements  */
            if ($( "#cell11" ).hasClass( "playero" ) && $( "#cell12" ).hasClass( "playero" ) && $( "#cell13" ).hasClass( "playero" )) {
            alert("player o wins!");
            playeroscore++;
            restartfunc();
        }
            /*cut out all other win statements*/

        });


    });


function restartfunc() {
    location.reload(true);
}


</script>
```

html

```
<p id="resetlink">
<a href="#" onclick="restartfunc()">Restart</a>
<BR><BR>

Player X Score: <span id="xscore"></span> 

    | 

Player O Score: <span id="oscore"></span>


<script>document.getElementById("oscore").innerHTML = player0score;</script>
```

Comment: You seem to have the variable `playeroscore` in your top code, but you use `player0score` at the bottom of the html.

Comment: You seem to be refreshing the page. Javascript won't remember the scores as the variables will be reset. You should use Localstorage in HTML5 to store the scores for each session.

Comment: yes i have changes it but still does not change the value when one of the player win if statements is ran

Comment: when the win if statement runs it does not refresh the page, i have taken the restartfunc() out and still same issue

Comment: Your restart function reloads the page, that will reset all your variables to their initial states, as mentioned already in the comments, you need to perpetuate your variables into the browser localstorage so they stick around after you reload the page.